# How to eliminate unnecessary repetition changing color of 2 columns?

Tags: excel, vba

My code changes color of two columns based on value.

There are repeated lines. Is there any way to reduce it?

```vb
Sub changecolor()
Dim cell As Range, i As Long
A = TimeSerial(0, 2, 0)
B = TimeSerial(0, 5, 0)
For i = 7 To 4000
    Set cell = Range("M" & i)
    Set cell2 = Range("N" & i)
    If cell.Value < A Then
        cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    ElseIf A < cell.Value And cell.Value > B Then
        cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Else
        cell.Interior.Color = vbBlue
    End If
    If cell2.Value < A Then
        cell2.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    ElseIf A < cell2.Value And cell2.Value > B Then
        cell2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Else
        cell2.Interior.Color = vbBlue
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It's much easier for people here to help you if you make your code easier to scan by *indenting* it.

Comment: [Select Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/select-case-statement) may do what you want. Is there a reason you are not using conditional formatting instead of using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

try looping through the range,
something like this

```
Sub changecolor()

Dim cell  As Range, rng As Range
Dim A As Variant, B As Variant

A = TimeSerial(0, 2, 0)
B = TimeSerial(0, 5, 0)

Set rng = Range("M7:N4000") ' the range to loop

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value < A Then
        cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    ElseIf A < cell.Value And cell.Value > B Then
        cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Else
        cell.Interior.Color = vbBlue
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```